# What to put inside jQuery(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Been trying to get a javascript gallery to run in wordpress, but I'm not too sure what to put into the .ready(function) in order to run the gallery. The original page to the jQuery function is here: http://manos.malihu.gr/simple-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery/2

I assume that I need to run some function that will run the entire javascript file, but I'm not quite sure what that function might be. Sorry for being so new to this, but thanks so much for any help!

```
function malihu_gallery() {
if (!is_admin()) {

    // Enqueue Malihu Gallery JavaScript
    wp_register_script('malihu-jquery-image-gallery', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/malihu-jquery-image-gallery.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('malihu-jquery-image-gallery'); 

    // Enqueue Malihu Gallery Stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'malihu-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/malihu_gallery.css', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('malihu-style' );

    function gallery_settings () { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // What do I put in here?
        });
    </script><?php
    }
  }
}

add_action('init', 'malihu_gallery');
```

Comment: Seems like the script has some $(window).load(function() embeded in it, so I'm not sure you need to add anything.

Comment: Are you using the full HTML/Javascript? Or just the Javascript?

Comment: I'm voting to close.  This is like asking, _"what do I put inside the `<body></body>`?"_ or _"what do I put inside my CSS file?"_

Comment: Thanks for the comments everybody. I'm using a similar version of the HTML and calling the javascript externally. I'm not sure if I actually need the extra settings in the functions php, but somebody told me that I would need to ready the function in order to keep the jQuery available for use. I would prefer to not add anything and keep all the options inside the .js file, but I'm not sure then why it wouldn't be running the javascript? 

Sorry, I'm still a bit new to this Sparky672. Just trying to figure out how to get this sweet slider working with Wordpress!

Comment: I have attached my index.php below incase, hopefully it will help. My HTML is almost the exact same as the example on malihu's site.

http://pastebin.com/hn8JNM4y

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, based on the limited view of the actual code, that this set of variables should be set/modified in that space:

```
//config
//set default images view mode
$defaultViewMode="full"; //full, normal, original
$tsMargin=30; //first and last thumbnail margin (for better cursor interaction) 
$scrollEasing=600; //scroll easing amount (0 for no easing) 
$scrollEasingType="easeOutCirc"; //scroll easing type 
$thumbnailsContainerOpacity=0.8; //thumbnails area default opacity
$thumbnailsContainerMouseOutOpacity=0; //thumbnails area opacity on mouse out
$thumbnailsOpacity=0.6; //thumbnails default opacity
$nextPrevBtnsInitState="show"; //next/previous image buttons initial state ("hide" or "show")
$keyboardNavigation="on"; //enable/disable keyboard navigation ("on" or "off")
```

Of course, this assumes these variables aren't already set in your '/js/malihu-jquery-image-gallery.js' file.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jason! When I check the source on my localhost it seems to be loading the script, but for some reason the changes aren't taking effect on the front-end of the site. I tried moving the code from the .js file to the functions.php like you had suggested, but it doesn't seem like there is a change. I'll keep trying!